# Why covering our nose with a cloth or nose mask reduces stale smell?

Tags: everyday-life, home-experiment, kinetic-theory

Whenever there is a stale smell in air, we tend to use a cloth(maybe a handkerchief) instantly to get away with it.

Why does a cloth or a mask reduce the intensity of a stale smell? Are the "smell" molecules getting filtered or absorbed or something else?

Comment: "Are the "smell" molecules getting filtered or absorbed ... ?" Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the masks work on the principle of adsorption. This is a surface phenomenon where particles stick to the surface of another material called adsorbent. Most commonly used material is activated charcoal.

When used is a smelly environment, the particles/molecules responsible for the smell are filtered first (this happens only for larger particles) and then the remaining ones are adsorbed on the surface of the charcoal. This gives you a cleaner air to breathe in.

Similar process occurs in clothes but the process is rather weak as compared to a professional grade mask.

Similar process is used in some water filters as well.